# Using permutations causes: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: scala, out-of-memory, permutation, heap-memory

I came across this problem when using permutations. I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

That's obviously because a list can not hold that much information. How do I approach this problem? Should I split my list into more lists so I could hold my information? I'm not giving any code because there is way to much of it.

Comment: Try increasing memory -Xmx<memory size>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generalised lazy permutations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796347/generalised-lazy-permutations-in-scala) **HUH? WAIT** What kind of "permutations" are those... Sorry, maybe bad duplicate proposal...

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what you are asking. The default implementation doesn't crash either. Calling `permutations` on a `List` returns an `Iterator[List[X]]`, and it produces elements lazily. If you are trying to *save* them all for some reason, then it's obviously your fault.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one implementation that enumerates permutations lazily:

```
def insertions[X](xs: List[X], y: X): Iterable[List[X]] = {
  val n = xs.size
  for (i <- 0 to n) yield {
    val (a, b) = xs.splitAt(i)
    a ++ (y :: b)
  }
}

def permutations[X](elems: List[X]): Stream[List[X]] = elems match {
  case Nil => Stream(Nil)
  case h :: t => permutations(t).flatMap(insertions(_, h))
}
```

For example,

```
permutations((0 to 10).toList) foreach println
```

will print all elements of the `Stream`.

**EDIT**

The question seemed to imply that `List.permutations` is implemented in some naive way that requires too much memory, but this is not so: the implementation in the standard library also produces an iterator that generates permutations one by one. So, one can just use

```
myList.permutations
```

instead. One only has to make sure that one doesn't try to save all those elements in a list at once.